# ubercart + paypal payments... 2 questions

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, paypal, ubercart

I'm planning to use paypal payment method together with ubercart, in order to not have to take care about security issues.

1)
I need to store the customers addresses in order to know where to ship the products.
I was wondering if I can let customer insert the addresses in paypal, and then somehow get them, or I should ask the customer to fill this information in the website instead... how ?

2) I need to test the checkout process. Is paypal offering a "testing proccess" in which I can see what happen without inserting credit cards numbers ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) People must give a delivery and billing adress in ubercart during checkout. There is also a nifty module wich let's user store different adresses and then choose wich one they want when checking out: http://drupal.org/project/uc_addresses

2) Yes, you can choose this option in the ubercart paypal module settings(sandbox mode) and you need to register here: https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: Thanks. 1) If I collect the addresses in ubercart with uc_addresses, I have to ask the customers to register ? Not anymore anonymous orders ? 2) How can I associate paypal payment receipt with customer addresses and store this in Drupal ?

Comment: 1) Obviously, but I'd always put on registration. Gives you an overview of customers.

2) Once a paypal payment is complete, the order-/paypaltransfernumber will automatically be marked as "paid via paypal". :)

Comment: 1) Let me insist on this point: I would really prefer to not ask customers to login... so I was wondering if I could just send an e-mail to store administrator with their address. In other terms, I would like to handle their address during the checkout process. If the checkout is canceled or finished, their address are deleted.. and eventually printed on the receipt. (I guess paypal send a receipt to the owner). Hope it was clear.  (2) Great :)

Comment: Yes, even with anonymous sohopping the user still has to give an adress. They just can't store it anywhere for future use. UC is quite expanded, I suggest looking around and testing it yourself to know what it can do. That's how I found out all these things.